# UISlider using Auto Layout won't resize

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I am using Constraints in XCODE and I have a Slider in between a few buttons on my interface however whenever I try to "Pin" my Sliders leading and trailing spacing to the superview it never works. I need the slider to scale according to the left and right edges up my view but nothing works. Any idea or does anybody know something I don't about UISliders in Auto-Layout?! [image: Before Scale - you can see the leading / trailing lines]

[image: Then it fails, everytime.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - DO NOT FORGET TO DELETE OTHER PINS IF YOU HAVE ANY ON THE SAME ELEMENT. Works great now.

:)